# MongoDB $match stage after $replaceRoot

Tags: mongodb, match, aggregate, root, reduce

Consider the following.
I have documents in which I save versions of fields.
Fields in the original document can null and I only save fields that actually changed.
For example:

```
{
    _id : abc,
    state : 'NEW',
    field2 : 'WILL NOT CHANGE',
    field3 : null,
    lastChange : 1236547
    changes : [
      {
         state : 'WORKING',
         field3 : 'SOMETHING'
      },
      {
         state : 'DONE'
      }
    ]
}
```

In my aggregation pipeline I build the latest version of the document by merging all versions with the document root. This means I avoid complex querys in which I search the changes array and find the latest version of every field I want to find and I benefit from the side effect that the pipeline will return the latest document version as a document. The pipeline below ends at the point where my problem is. In the application there are more stages following that do counting and grouping etc.

```
Mongoose: meldungs.aggregate([
{
    '$match': {
        '$and': [{
            lastChange: {
                '$ne': null
            }
        },
        {
            lastChange: {
                '$gte': ISODate('2017-03-01T23:00:00.000Z')
            }
        },
        {
            lastChange: {
                '$lt': ISODate('2017-03-02T22:59:59.999Z')
            }
        }]
    }
},
{
    '$replaceRoot': {
        newRoot: {
            '$arrayToObject': {
                '$reduce': {
                    input: '$changes',
                    initialValue: {
                        '$filter': {
                            input: {
                                '$objectToArray': '$$ROOT'
                            },
                            as: 'field',
                            cond: {
                                '$and': [
                                  { $ne : [ '$$field.v', null ] },
                                  { $ne : [ '$$field.k', '_id' ] }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    in: {
                        '$concatArrays': ['$$value',
                        {
                            '$filter': {
                                input: {
                                    '$objectToArray': '$$this.changes'
                                },
                                as: 'field',
                                cond: {
                                  $ne : [ '$$field.v', null ]
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
{
  '$match': {
     state: { '$eq': 'DONE' }
  }
],
{})
```

This is working great and the new document looks as expected:

```
{
    state : 'DONE',
    field2 : 'WILL NOT CHANGE',
    field3 : 'SOMETHING',
    lastChange : 1236547
}
```

My problem ist that the matching stage that follows the merge/reduce fails to 'query' the new document. Instead the old field values seem to be used.

```
state: { '$eq': 'DONE' } // should return the document, but doesn't
state: { '$eq': 'NEW' } // should NOT return the document but does
```

My best guess is that this has something to do with pipeline optimization? Meaning the optimizer moves the $match statement into the first stage, or something like that.
Does anybody had this problem as well and knows a solution?

### **Udpate 1**

After more testing it seems that using $$ROOT as the initialValue of the reduce is part of the problem. If I use an empty array as the initialValue I can $match the reduced fields correctly.

Comment: Clearly this does not actually work as you are expecting. You should really be looking at the ouput "before" the `$match` stage. Not sure what you are expecting but I would presume you are expecting the last value of "state" in the array to be the returned value. If this is the case then simply select the last value in the array. Or better yet simply prepend to the array so the latest entry is always the first. Looks more like you are trying to find use for aggregation operators you don't really understand than solve an actual problem.

Comment: In the question please. That's where you put details and not in comments. Comments are for people like me asking the people asking the questions like yourself to clarify points in their question. So please edit your question instead of trying to post sample output in comments. But my overall point is that it cannot possibly actually look like you are expecting if the `$match` condition fails.

Comment: I have edited my question, thanks for the hint. I do know how to debug my code though and the stage before the $match does produce output as expected, but I am glad that this seems to be a more complex problem than just me overlooking something ;)

Comment: Can you run the explain to check the order in which the stages are evaluated ? Also, take a look at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27213

Comment: The order of execution is not changed. The explain shows that the first match is moved to the cursor query, than follows the replaceRoot and than the last match...

Comment: Have you tried preprocessing some parts of your query (e.g. the `$objectToArray: $$ROOT` bit) in a `$project` stage before the magic `$replaceRoot` stage? I generally avoid attempting to do so much in just one stage simply because it makes my queries easier to understand/debug.